# Undeletable element in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm wondering if there's a way to make an element 'undeletable' in CKEditor 4.

I might have some HTML like so:

```
<div class='content' contenteditable='true'>
    <div class='gallery'>...</div>
</div>
```

In this case `.gallery` shouldn't be able to be deleted from `.content`, either by backspacing or selecting and pressing delete.

**UPDATE: It seems widgets can not be undeletable, or at least from what I can tell.**
Take a look at http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets, the widgets can be deleted. Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are widgets. [They will be implemented in CKEditor 4.3](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9764) and provide this kind of features. Be patient ;)

At the moment there's only [placeholder](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder) plugin that does "similar" thing, but I guess this is not enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

I use a workaround to make widgets undeletable. In the widget definition, I added this to the init property:

```
    init: function () {
        this.on('key', function(e) {
            let k = e.data.keyCode;
            // Backspace, delete, ctrl+x
            if ([8, 46, 1114200].includes(k)) { e.cancel() }
        })
    }
```

It will prevent the user from deleting the widget using the keyboard. The "cut" function needs to be disabled too.