# CKEditor undeletable widget

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to make a widget unable to be deleted by the user in CKEditor 4.6.1?

I am using the widget as a wrapper for text that users will expand upon, similar to a writing prompt. I don't want them to accidentally be able to delete the widget and confuse them and my code logic.

I have tried `mask: true` and `contenteditable=false`, but these only protect the content of the widget. The entire widget can still be deleted if the user gets backspace-happy.

Is this functionality possible? This post ([Undeletable element in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140267/undeletable-element-in-ckeditor)) from 2013 seems to suggest it will be, but I can't find anything in the docs and I'm new to CKEditor widget development.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am in the same boat...

Comment: Nope, I've looked through the docs (and even the v3.x ones too), but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Ok. i think we have to then check the content on-load also check if there is a widget destroy event, then reload the widget programmatically while somehow reverting the data inside the widget again. Maybe saving the content every 2 seconds and the reverting the data then readding the widget afterwards.